# tx_news category menu doesnt filter news- TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, tx-news

I need to configure a news category menu in my site. I list all news in one column and the other column in the same page shows the category menu. News list and category menu is configured using plugin not by TypoScript. The same page contain another news listing for another purpose.
The problem is the news doesn't get filterd by category.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you set set the page properties to "No Cache" to make sure, caching is not the problem. If caching can be exluded as the problem, please check your list plugin settings -> second tab -> last option "Disable override demand" should NOT be checked.

Comment: another prerequisite is that you have to set the  Category mode of the list plugin to "Show items with selected categories (OR)". But don't select any categories then.

Comment: @mtness add your comment as an answer as it's valid one too.

Answer (score 2):

another prerequisite is that you have to set the Category mode of the list plugin to "Show items with selected categories (OR)". But don't select any categories then. from – mtness